# Error that UITableViewCell with IBOutlet named `imageView` conflicts with superclass IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have made a custom UITableViewCell in which I have added 2 labels and one UIImageView, each with IBOutlets.

```
IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

I've given the UIImageView an IBOutlet named `imageView`, but after adding it I am getting error:

> Getter for 'imageView' with Objective-C selector 'imageView' conflicts with getter for 'imageView' from superclass 'UITableViewCell' with the same Objective-C selector"

[image]

How can I fix this error? Is there any way to use an IBOutlet named `imageView` in a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: try to change name of the outlet

Comment: thanks @VishalSonawane i changed the name and the error was gone , didnt know because of name also you can get error , and even after getting error i was not able to solve .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting this error since UITableViewCell has its own imageView property and you are making an outlet of name imageView which will conflict with its super class(UITableViewCell) property name(imageView) which is a getter method. So, you just need to change the name of the outlet.

Comment: yes Priya i have got it from @SahebRoy and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of the outlet as everyone is suggesting, as tableviewCell has its own `imageView` property, so when you are assigning another outlet with the name of `imageView` the getter methods are getting conflicted

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you, so that later on when anyone stumbles across the same problem, they can solve this themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change its name f.e. to `photoView`. Now it is overriding property from it's super class which is `imageView`.